# handle X on toolbar for gtk-sharp window

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I would like to handle the event where a user clicks on the "X" of a gtk window using GTK-sharp.  I don't know what signal is called when this occurs.  The end goal would be to simply hide the window, instead of destroying it and removing all of its internal widgets.

Answer (score 0):

use the OnDeleteEvent, and set this.visible = false, and make the RetVal for the event = true.

Comment: There's a convenience function for this: just connect Widget.DeleteEvent to Widget.HideOnDelete().